# DataGridView custom column accessing design time parameters at run time

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-component

I have been playing with some sample code which implements a datepicker column for a DataGridView.

Where I'm struggling is in how to appropriately access design time parameters (thanks to Bradley Smith for the tip on overriding the Clone method) in the CalendarEditingControl where I want to set the Format to the DateFormat.

I've provided the complete sample below and to see where I want to use DateFormat if you just scan for the comment:
//*********************** I'd like to set the Format to the design time value provided inDataGridViewCalendarColumn.DateFormat here ***********************//

thanks

Matt

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApplication.Components
{
    public class DataGridViewCalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewCalendarColumn()
            : base(new CalendarCell())
        {
        }

```
    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell. 
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;

        }
    }

    public DateTimePickerFormat DateFormat { get; set; }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        DataGridViewCalendarColumn clone = (DataGridViewCalendarColumn)base.Clone();
        clone.DateFormat = this.DateFormat;
        return clone;
    }

}

public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    public CalendarCell(): base()
    {
        // Use the short date format. 
        this.Style.Format = "d";
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value. 
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        CalendarEditingControl ctl =
            DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
        // Use the default row value when Value property is null. 
        if (this.Value == null)
        {
            ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        }
        else
        {
            ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses. 
            return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains. 

            return typeof(DateTime);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the current date and time as the default value. 
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }


}

class CalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public CalendarEditingControl()
    {
        //*********************** I'd like to set the Format to the design time value provided inDataGridViewCalendarColumn.DateFormat here ***********************//
        //(instead of hard coding it to DateTimePickerFormat.Short)
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue  
    // property. 
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is String)
            {
                try
                {
                    // This will throw an exception of the string is  
                    // null, empty, or not in the format of a date. 
                    this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // In the case of an exception, just use the  
                    // default value so we're not left with a null 
                    // value. 
                    this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Implements the  
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method. 
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the  
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method. 
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex  
    // property. 
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey  
    // method. 
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed. 
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit  
    // method. 
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property. 
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlValueChanged property. 
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingPanelCursor property. 
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell 
        // have changed.
        valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is apply the `DateFormat` property from the column onto the editing control. In the `InitializeEditingControl` method, add the following line:

```
ctl.Format = (OwningColumn as DataGridViewCalendarColumn).DateFormat;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Bradley, that's great.  The last hurdle is that I'm using the custom column in multiple columns e.g. start and end date and have added an additional DefaultDate property.  What is happening is that both columns are getting the same value even though they are set to different values.  Do I need to manage an array of values or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @mattpm Do you mean the same DateFormat value or the same DateTime value?

Comment: I mean the same DateTime value.  I have resolved it by moving the line of code 
ctl.DefaultDate = (OwningColumn as DataGridViewCalendarColumn).DefaultDate;

before the line 
base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms (and WebForms, and WPF...) you don't get access to the design-time values in the constructor.  Instead, the Framework invokes your no-arg constructor, then uses the appropriate property setters on your object to finish initializing it.

Setting default values for your object's properties in the constructor is a sensible thing to do in case the designer-user doesn't specify at design time what all the property values  should be.  So your constructor is good as-is.